# How do I extract a value in a cell if it's followed by a specific text? EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I extract a value in a cell if it's followed by a specific text?

For example, Cell A2 contains "12 Count (Pack of 3) (Compatible with 2.0 Brewers)". I want to grab the value of 12 if it's followed by the word "count".

Comment: Do you have any chance to have few other words before 12? Can you post few more sample?

Comment: Hello, here are two more 1. Peet's Coffee K-Cup Packs, Big Bang Medium Roast, 60 Count 2. San Francisco Bay OneCup, Hazelnut Crème, 36 Count- Single Serve Coffee, Compatible with Keurig K-cup Brewers, Flavored, 13.97 oz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have any word before your desired text then use-

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1," Count")
```

If desired word situated in middle of sentence then could try-

```
=TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTBEFORE(A2," Count")," "),,-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Result]

My approach is here in **B3** cell,

=LEFT(CONCAT(IFERROR(--MID(A3,SEQUENCE(LEN(A3)),1),"")),2)

if your excel doesn't support for sequence, then try with in **B4** cell,

=LEFT(CONCAT(IFERROR(--MID(A4,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A4))),1),"")),2)